# How to deleteAllObjects from NSSet

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

I have a method here which counts the number of annotations on my map view. However, every time this method is called, annCount keeps on incrementing. For example, there are 5 annotations on the map - the first time this method is called it returns 5 as expected. But the second time it's called it returns 11, then 16, 21, 26 and so on..

```
MKMapRect visibleMapRect = myMapView.visibleMapRect;
NSSet *visibleAnnotations = [myMapView annotationsInMapRect:visibleMapRect];
annCount = [visibleAnnotations count];


NSLog(@"%u", annCount);
return annCount;
```

I was thinking if I could clear all objects from NSSet it would work properly. However, the NSSET won't recognise deleteAllObjects. I have tried NSMutableSet but it doesn't work with "annotationsInMapRect:visibleMapRect". Cheers.

Comment: NSSet doesn't care about the same objects being located within its indexes. Try using NSMutableArray when doing this, and see if it changes any

Comment: How can I use NSMutableArray? I will get the error _Incompatible pointer types initializing 'NSMutableArray *' with an expression of type 'NSSet *'_

Comment: `NSSet` is an immutable collection, meaning once it is created, it cannot be modified. Using an array is not going to help, because `annotationsInMapRect:` returns a set. Your problem lies not within the set, but why `annotationsInMapRect:` returns more and more annotations - this is what you need to investigate.

Comment: you can use a mutable nsset for it , where removeAllObjects is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not with the `NSSet` that was returned. Your problem is `annotationsInMapRect:` is returning more objects than you expected. This leads me to believe that you add more and more annotations to your map (perhaps by mistake).

`NSSet` is an immutable collection, so you cannot add or remove objects from an instance. What more, when the `visibleAnnotations` is released, it releases all the objects in it. Since `annotationsInMapRect:` returns a **new object**, it would not matter even if you were able to call `removeAllObjects`.

Comment: I agree, OP has problem in his addAnnotations without removing.

Comment: Thanks Leo. Yes, there was an issue with more and more annotations getting added to the map each time. However, there is still an issue where annCount is returning 1 even when no annotation is on screen. I will investigate further on that one.

Comment: @user3690669 If the count is one, try printing the annotation and see what it is and when it was added.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. It turns out that the circle showing the user's current location was being counted as 1 annotation...